# C - fgets weird behaviour

Tags: c, popen, fgets

It may be a stupid issue but its been a few hours I've been looking around to fix that and it drives me crazy.

That little code works perfectly fine if the fgets line is commentated (as provided).
As soon as I remove the comment the whole function will NOT do anything at all. My process jut freezes - even the printf before the fgets isnt executed.

```
void RetirerTransaction(char* filePath, char* transaction) {
    FILE* f;
    FILE* result;
    char tempStr[128];
    char line[100];

    printf(">>%s<<",filePath); // Just to check everything is ok

    strcpy(tempStr,"grep -v \"");
    strcat(tempStr,transaction);
    strcat(tempStr,"\"");
    strcat(tempStr,filePath); // tempStr = grep -v "XXX" myfile

    result = popen(tempStr, "r");
    /*
    if (fgets(line,100,result)) {
        printf("OK");
    }
    */
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you check the result of `popen()`? Maybe it fails to open the pipe, so your program just crashes when trying to use `result` in `fgets()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how shall i check its result ? I did a printf of my tempStr and the command is fine (if I write it down in the term it will return the correct lines).

Comment: Most likely, the process you opened hasn't output an entire line (or 100 characters) so your code is waiting for it.

Comment: Nice it works! Was the missing space messing it up. Actually it doesnt matter that it receives 100 chars or 1 - it still will work. Thanks everyone for your answers, i cant believe it was something as stupid as a space, w/e :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a space between the closing quote of the pattern and the file parameter for grep. That makes the whole thing including the filename be taken as the pattern.

By default, grep reads from standard input. It blocks trying to read from stdin because it doesn't have a file parameter.

Add the space like this and you'll be fine:

`strcat(tempStr,"\" ");`

Comment: Yes thank you it made the job ;) didnt f5 before answering so didnt see it was posted as an answer. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below.Please add check for the popen return value. If popen fails and you are trying to do a fgets() then it might cause crash.

```
result = popen(tempStr, "r");
if(result == NULL)
return;
else
fgets(line,100,result);
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt change anything. Was the missing space after my grep that was making it crash.